# How to find transfer function from a graph

Tags: transfer-function

I need help to find the transfer function of the system from this input/output graph:
[image]

Comment: From long ago 10~90% T = 0.35/f(-3dB)  Compare both then determine gain and offset

Comment: @ Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 : Tried solving this ...If TF=K/s+a form, then a=1/T=20 and finding value of K by steady state error formula  for step response we get K=a=20.So, TF=20/S+20..Is this correct ?

Comment: your photo needs cropping, and optimally a bit of rotation, and better lighting; [here's some advice on taking better photos of drawings](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7232/64158) (ignore the part specific to schematics

Comment: @anie Note that you have a time delay. Looks to me like about \$25\:\text{ms}\$. This tells you something about the transfer equation's numerator. Do you remember what?

Comment: Where did these waveforms come from?

Comment: This is a problem which I came across...The only thing that was specified is that this is a input/output graph of a linear measurement device and need to find out the transfer function.

Comment: Do you understand my answer? Or have any questions?

Comment: @anie The \$25\:\text{ms}\$ delay implies that the factor, \$e^{{-25\,\text{ms}\cdot s}}\$, will be included in the transfer function's numerator.

Answer (score 1):

Since the input is not a Heaviside Step function, we cannot presume this is a frequency-domain problem but rather a non-linear function of gain and offset.

Not knowing where this sketch comes from, let me assume it a quasi-linear so that the gain exists above some threshold and is saturated or null gain elsewhere. Consider tolerances as loose as the sketch for now.

Examine the **Vout vs Vin** and **Avg** to obtain **gain and offset.**

Using coarse estimates

```
t (ms) 0 to 25 to 50 +   Linear Mean
in     0 to  1  to 2      1.5
out    0 to  0  to 2      1  
gain   0 to  0==2==0 
offset = out-in         -0.5

gain=2   (for in = 1 to 2, otherwise =0)
offset = -0.5*2=-1  

**out = 2*(in-1)=in*2-2  (for in = 1 to 2)**

(rev B)
```

When amplifiers saturate, the linear gain =0 in this case for in<1 and in>2.  But in the linear out range, the gain ~ 2.

The soft edges mean there is a compressed range where the gain changes from 0 to 2 to 0.

In this plot, there is no observable filter except on the previous input signals.

A simulation.
[image]